# how to revert changes on value inside input field using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Highlight row when selected.
    $(function () {
        $('#Cases tr').click(function () {
            $('#Cases tr').removeClass('selectedRow');
            $(this).addClass('selectedRow');
        });
    });

    //Display selected row data in text input.
    var table = document.getElementById("Cases"), rIndex;

    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        table.rows[i].onclick = function () {
            rIndex = this.rowIndex;
            console.log(rIndex);

            document.getElementById("DepartmentCase").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("Department").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("Charge").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("LabCase").value = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("IncidentReportDate").value = this.cells[4].innerHTML;
        };
    } 
 

     //Disable or enable input box 
        $("#DepartmentCase").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#Department").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#Charge").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#LabCase").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#IncidentReportDate").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#Save").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Cancel").prop("disabled", true);


    //Edit Button Function

    $("#Edit").click(function () {
        $("#DepartmentCase").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#Department").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#Charge").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#LabCase").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#IncidentReportDate").prop("disabled", false).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
        $("#Edit").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Save").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#Cancel").prop("disabled", false);
    });

    //Save Button Functions
    $("#Save").click(function () {
        table.rows[rIndex].cells[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById("DepartmentCase").value;
        table.rows[rIndex].cells[1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("Department").value;
        table.rows[rIndex].cells[2].innerHTML = document.getElementById("Charge").value;
        table.rows[rIndex].cells[3].innerHTML = document.getElementById("LabCase").value;
        table.rows[rIndex].cells[4].innerHTML = document.getElementById("IncidentReportDate").value;
        $("#DepartmentCase").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Department").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Charge").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#LabCase").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#IncidentReportDate").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Edit").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#Save").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Cancel").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#dialog-1").dialog("open");
      
    });

    //For dialog box
     $("#dialog-1").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true
    });
    
    //Cancel Button Function

    $("#Cancel").click(function () {
        $("#DepartmentCase").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Department").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Charge").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#LabCase").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#IncidentReportDate").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Edit").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#Save").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Cancel").prop("disabled", true);




    });


});
```

```css
#Cases {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#Cases td, #cases th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#Cases tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
#Cases tr.selectedRow{background-color: #56bff0}
#Cases tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
#Cases tr{cursor: pointer}
#Cases th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #455382;
  color: white;
}
#container{
        margin:0 auto;
        width:80%;
        overflow:auto;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<html>


<body>


<h2>
        Recent Cases
    </h2>
    <table id="Cases">
  <tr>
    <th>Department Case #</th>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>Charge</th>
    <th>Lab Case #</th>
    <th>Incident Report Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-383</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2011</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-321</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-456</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2012</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-789</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Duping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2013</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-356</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2014</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-297</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2015</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-393</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Duping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-382</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-023</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2018</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-083</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2019</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p><b>Case Details</b></p><br />

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Department Case #</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Department Case #"  id="DepartmentCase" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Department</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Department"  id="Department" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Charge</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Charge"  id="Charge" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lab Case #</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Lab Case"  id="LabCase" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Incident Report Date</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Incident Report Date"  id="IncidentReportDate" value=""/></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<br/>


<table> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="Edit" id="Edit" onclick=""/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Save" id="Save" onclick=""/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Cancel" id="Cancel" onclick=""/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

I have a table with static data in it, I've already finished the edit and save functions. Basically, the main function of the code is when you clicked the 1st row(let's assume that the table has five row) the data from it will be put inside in their respected input fields and the user can edit, save, cancel changes on the those row values. Problem is I don't know how to revert the changes inside the input box when cancel is clicked. I will put the code and example scenario.

Sampl scecnario, if i clicked on first row it will populate inside the input field(example i will edit department case# :123-12345-1234-382 to 123) and clicked cancel, it should be back to 123-12345-1234-382, the logic in cancel is it should display the last saved value in the row.

This the html table

```
  <body>
    <h2>
    Recent Cases
   </h2>
  <table id="Cases">
  <tr>
 <th>Department Case #</th>
<th>Department</th>
<th>Charge</th>
<th>Lab Case #</th>
<th>Incident Report Date</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>123-12345-1234-382</td>
<td>Forti-Palmade</td>
<td>Illegal Dumping</td>
<td>10-123456</td>
<td>05/03/2017</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>123-12345-1234-023</td>
<td>Forti-Palmade</td>
<td>Illegal Dumping</td>
<td>10-123456</td>
<td>05/03/2018</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>123-12345-1234-083</td>
<td>Forti-Palmade</td>
<td>Illegal Dumping</td>
<td>10-123456</td>
<td>05/03/2019</td>
</tr>
</table>

this is the input field 

     <table>
   <tr>
   <td>Department Case #</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Department Case #"  id="DepartmentCase" 
   value=""/></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Department</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Department"  id="Department" value=""/> 
   </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Charge</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Charge"  id="Charge" value=""/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Lab Case #</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Lab Case"  id="LabCase" value=""/></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Incident Report Date</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="Incident Report Date"  
     id="IncidentReportDate" value=""/></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
   <table> 
   <tr>
   <td><input type="button" value="Edit" id="Edit" onclick=""/></td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Save" id="Save" onclick=""/></td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Cancel" id="Cancel" onclick=""/></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </html>
```

This is the Jquery/Javascript

```
//Display selected row data in text input.

var table = document.getElementById("Cases"), rIndex;

for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    table.rows[i].onclick = function () {
        rIndex = this.rowIndex;
        console.log(rIndex);

        document.getElementById("DepartmentCase").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("Department").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("Charge").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("LabCase").value = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("IncidentReportDate").value = this.cells[4].innerHTML;
    };
}
```

this is the JS for edit and save

```
//Edit Button Function

$("#Edit").click(function () {
    $("#DepartmentCase").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#Department").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#Charge").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#LabCase").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#IncidentReportDate").prop("disabled", false).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
    $("#Edit").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Save").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#Cancel").prop("disabled", false);
});

//Save Button Functions
$("#Save").click(function () {
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById("DepartmentCase").value;
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("Department").value;
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[2].innerHTML = document.getElementById("Charge").value;
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[3].innerHTML = document.getElementById("LabCase").value;
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[4].innerHTML = document.getElementById("IncidentReportDate").value;
    $("#DepartmentCase").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Department").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Charge").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#LabCase").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#IncidentReportDate").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Edit").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#Save").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Cancel").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#dialog-1").dialog("open");

});
```

Comment: create a fiddle ot it/

Comment: What is "it"?  The input field?  The cell text? Did you click save yet? Please create a snippet and be a bit more clear about what you're doing and what you expect to happen.

Comment: the row cell value will populate the input fields and then if you make some changes in the value, it will revert back. example : (original :cat ) (lets say i added "ex" : catex) click cancel and value inside the input box will be back on "cat"

Comment: i included a snippet

Comment: Why are you disabling the save and canceled button on Save clicked?

Comment: its part of the logic that I was creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay as I get your point is to revert the change you just made on input fields as you click the canceled button.

So what you have to do is just get the last selected row index and re-populate the data from row.

To re-populate the data from the row you just need to click that row programmatically

So just added the event handler for canceled button and you have done.

```
$('#Cancel').click(function(){

     if (rIndex)
        $('#Cases tr').eq(rIndex).click();

});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but is there possible way if I clicked cancel it should automatically re-populate the input fields/display the last saved value. It's like undoing the changes in text value

Comment: yes, it is undoing/or last saved values in the table both are the same.

Comment: i mean is there is another way, that doesnt include clicking the row again repopulated the input field.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to do the same thing but this is better to click the row again to reduce to re-write the code.

Comment: Are you not willing to show data in the input fields when clicked on cancel ??

Comment: after clicking the cancel it should automatically revert on the input field, input should be staying on the input field in the whole process

Comment: What do you mean by `revert on the input fields, the input should be staying on the input`?

Comment: for example, if you click first row it populate the input fields right, now i want to change the text in the first input field(sample text: "cat" ) and i change it to cat123(without saving it just editing the text inside the input field) if clicked cancel, it should automatically back to "cat".( without clicking the row also)

Comment: thank you some much you helped me. sorry for the misunderstanding